# Why does Python seem to behave differently between a call with pytest and a "manual" call?

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.8

### Context

I want to test the behavior of a singleton class when used in multiprocessing environment because it has been brought to my attention that it does not work properly. It seems the same object is being used in two different processes.

### Minimal example

- Python 3.8.3
- Windows 10 enterprise X64
- pytest 6.1.2

#### singleton.py

```py
from threading import Lock
class SingletonMeta(type):
    _instances = {}
    _lock = Lock()
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        with cls._lock:
            if cls not in cls._instances:
                cls._instances[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

#### manual_test.py

```py
from singleton import SingletonMeta
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Test(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

def do(value):
    t = Test(value)
    return t.value, id(t)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(2) as pool:
       values = [1, 2]
       results = pool.map(do, values)
       results.sort()
       print("results: ", results)
```

#### test_multiprocessing.py

```py
from singleton import SingletonMeta
import pytest
from multiprocessing import Pool


class Singleton(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

def do(value):
    t = Singleton(value=value)
    return t.value, id(t)

def test_multiprocess():
    # given
    value1 = 1
    value2 = 2
    # when
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        results = pool.map(do, [value1, value2])
    
    results.sort()
    print("results", results)
    # then
    assert results[0][0] == value1
    assert results[1][0] == value2
```

### manual_test.py output

```
$ python manual_test.py 
results:  [(1, 2076407268784), (1, 2076407268784)]
```

As you can see, the `value` and the object's id are the same for both processes.

### pytest output

note: truncated to remove noise

```
$ pytest -rA -v -p no:faulthandler
results [(1, 2356600174768), (2, 2732965816496)]
```

As you can see, both the values and the object's id are different.

### Problem

Given that these two programs have almost the very same code, I was expecting to have the same behavior for both:

- The first value of the set should be se same
- The id of the objects should be the same

However, this is only the case when calling manual_test.py, not with the pytest utility. My final goal is to have my class work in multiprocessing and test it in my library, hence I would like to know:

- why is pytest behaving differently ? (or the other way arround, I am not sure which one is the "correct" behavior)
- if the pytest behavior is "incorrect" (at least unexpected), how can I fix it ?

Comment: What happens if you make your tests consistent (either use `value1  = 1; value2 = 2` in both or use `values = [1, 2]` in both)?

Comment: What OS are you using? You didn't specify which start method to use, so the default for your OS is being chosen. At a glance, it seems like which start method is being used may be relevant for explaining the behavior you're seeing

Comment: @chepner The result is the same, in both ways.

Comment: @Brian Windows 10 64 bits, python 3.8.3, pytest 6.1.2. What do you mean by "start method".

Comment: @Itération122442 See [multiprocessing - Contexts and start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual test passes due to a timing issue (or rather, due to lack of spent time/resources); while I'm not versed in how python decides to allocate pooled processes to given tasks, this can be demonstrated quite easily by checking the process id:

```
def do(value):
    t = Test(value)
    return t.value, id(t), os.getpid()
```

will result in

```
results:  [(1, 4311792512, 24184), (1, 4311792512, 24184)]
```

Which are the same, as you already observed. However;
adding some computation or time to this function would change the results:

```
def do(value):
    t = Test(value)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return t.value, id(t), os.getpid()
->
results:  [(1, 4321196928, 24285), (2, 4338334592, 24286)]
```

or

```
def do(value):
    t = Test(value)
    for x in range(100000):
        pass
    return t.value, id(t), os.getpid()
->
results:  [(1, 4387257264, 24358), (2, 4338498480, 24359)]
```

pytest might be adding just enough overhead to cause the difference.

---

The main issue here is the difference between threads and processes; while `threading.Lock` works well for threads, a thread lock has no effect over a different process. On the other hand, while you can switch to using `multiprocessing.Lock` for the singleton, it can only prevent simultaneous creation of it, and does not guarantee one single class across all processes. This is because even after creation of a class, the `cls._instances` dictionary is not shared/synced across all processes.

There are various synchronization mechanisms that can handle such coordination, but the best fit depends on the specific use-case - what is to be achieved, and what should be prevented.

Comment: Good catch, thank you. So what happens is that process X is used twice and the state of the singleton is not "cleared" between each set of instructions, right ?

Comment: Well, I guess you can say that, but I have a feeling that would be an awkward way of looking at this. I mean, the purpose of a singleton is to be unique in the first place, so "clearing" its state to make another one kinda defeats the purpose, no?

Comment: Yes, indeed. However we faced a very specific problem where we need different configuration from times to times of a class inheriting the singleton. But that's another story.

Comment: I feel like I've done enough "damage" for one day, but then again - I might be on a roll here ;). Python is quite permissive as opposed to some other languages; while I've seen some cases where singletons are useful, python may frown upon but does not actively prevent anyone from poking around private methods. Have you considered utilizing class's `__new__` method instead? I found that such approach might be more readable and maintainable than Metaclasses, and makes for much easier inheritance. Might not fit, just a thought.

Comment: Ugh I wouldn’t mess with this at all - just initialize your state variables once and pass them to the processes as config. Don’t rely on singletons at all when multiprocessing.

Comment: @micromoses You are not damaging anything. I'm taking everything I can. I'll have a look at that, while taking into account Delgado's comment ;)